# Facebook Post Feed Not Displaying Description

Tags: facebook, api, post, feed

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed',
                                'post',
                                {
                                    access_token: pageAccessToken,
                                    message: "Title: " + $("#title").val() + "\nDescription: " + $("#description").val(),
                                    link: shareUrl,
                                    picture: imageUrl,
                                    source: imageUrl,
                                    icon: imageUrl,
                                    name: $("#title").val(),
                                    from: pageId,
                                    caption: $("#description").val(),
                                    description: $("#description").val(),
                                    published: true
                                },
                                function (response) {
                                    //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                                    finishedPublish++;
                                    if (finishedPublish >= totalPage) {
                                        window.location.href = "/post/Index/?shareImage=" + imageUrl + " &shareUrl=" + shareUrl;
                                    }
                                });
```

I have the following code above and i'm trying to figure out why facebook description is not displaying when the post is shared and is still picking up from the link that was shared?

Comment: duplicate thread headline is about the picture parameter, but the question is the exact same. all those parameters are deprecated with v2.9, see changelog.

Comment: I think it's a little bit different issue..that one was FB.UI this one is for API

Comment: the changes affect everything, the parameters don´t even exist in the api reference anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed

Comment: they changed it for a good reason: with those parameters, you could just set ANY data and hide the real open graph data. people always need to know what they can expect behind a link.